# How to Convert complex hierarchical Datatable to json?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-3.0

I am trying to convert my following `datatable` into `json` but no luck till now.

`Datatable` like:

```
<b>Name    Address</b>

companies   addresses
companies   bids
companies   commitments
companies   evaluations
companies    Null
```

I want `json` to be like this where name is `null` that will be the parent node and with the same parent node text child comes inside that parent node.

```
{
  "Name": "companies",
  "Address": [
    {
      "addresses",
      "bids","commitments", "evaluations"
    }
  ]
}
```

Writing this code in `C#`.

Comment: '{ "Name": "companies", "Address": [ { "addresses", "bids","commitments", "evaluations" } ] }' is what you get or is what you want? this didn't seem to be valid JSON though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *LINQ* to group your data by `Name` and ignore the address with `null` value in that group. Finally you can use *Newtonsoft JSON* to convert your projected data to *json* string like this:-

```
var result = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Name"))
               .Select(x => new
                       {
                           Name = x.Key,
                           Address = x.Where(z => z.Field<string>("Address") != null)
                                      .Select(z => z.Field<string>("Address")).ToList()
                       });

string jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

[Sample Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cDzhqM)